# Setting up multiple github accounts to use with visual studio in Windows

Tags: windows, github, github-for-windows

I tried following the steps in https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574 but it fails in the very first step. I am using **Windows 10**

I ran the ssh-keygen command in gitbash but got the following error:
[image]

My user name has a space in between, so how do I deal with this to setup my github accounts? Thanks.

Comment: Try enclosing the entire directory in double quotes, and remove the one that is currently before `/.ssh`

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of Git, [I recommend adding `-m PEM`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309), and, in your case, the target file path:

```
 cd /c/Users/Ab*
 mkdir .ssh
 chmod 700 .ssh
 cd .ssh
 ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -m PEM -f ./id_rsa
```