# Omnibus Gitlab SSH connection issue

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I have Gitlab servers set up behind ELB on aws. I have an issue with SSH connection over port 22.
I have opened up 22 port from classic ELB to end servers. I have also added an ssh public key (id_rsa.pub) in web gitlab console.
When I run “ssh -Tv git@myserver.com”, I keep getting the following error -

```
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/.ssh/id_rsa RSA 
SHA256:lL1iDEdfgdf5452+VYx4+K234jsddfIto47/vMT1Q0J7SdA explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi- 
keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/.ssh/id_rsa RSA 
SHA256:lL1iDEdfgdf5452+VYx4+K234jsddfIto47/vMT1Q0J7SdA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi- 
keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@mydomain.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi- 
with-mic).
```

I am not sure what I am missing since I have opened up a connection to end server over 22. Seems Gitlab is not able to authenticate the public key. Can you please help here?

Comment: Can someone please help here?

Comment: Does your private SSH key have 64 or 70 characters per lines?

Comment: It has 70 characters per line, but what's to do with that?

Comment: new OPENSSH keys are not always compatible with remote SSH server. Regenerate it as PEM, not OPENSSH. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309. If that works well, I will post an answer later today.

Comment: I think that's not a case with me because I am running the same set up without HA in aws and able to ssh successfully with the same keys. 
FYI - I have 2 Gtilab servers running behind ELB and having shared NFS..In this case its not working over SSH

Comment: Ok. I would still test it, just to rule that out.

Comment: Tested with new PEM keys...still the same error

Comment: OK. Not much to add except possibly to have a look at the remote SSH daemon log, which would be more detailed.

Comment: where can I find that logs exactly?

Comment: On the server side, if you have access to it: https://serverfault.com/a/480433/783