# GitLab requesting password after SSH-KEY registered

Tags: linux, git, ssh, gitlab, git-commit

I have a problem. I generated a ssh key with `"ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "GitLab" -b 4096"`, after that I loaded the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` content into Profile Settings -> SSH Keys.

After that I tried to go into a directory and type `"git clone git@gitlab.cs.pub.ro:/l2-pa-project-BITpick.git"` (where  is my user) and it prompts me to input a password and I don't know what password is that (it's not PC password and not either the account password).

I searched on the internet and I saw that I can test that running `"ssh -vT git@gitlab.cs.pub.ro"` and it prompts me the following:

I tried to reinstall git, delete .ssh folder, delete the folder that I wanted to clone into. I also tried to regen another key, I followed the GitLab tutorial for key generation. Nothing from that worked.

```
mihai@barebone:~$ ls ~/.ssh
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/P5nGzCM.png]

I expected to easily push the files.

Comment: paste code, not external link to screenshot of your code.

Comment: It might be the password of your ssh keys. Did you input any password during generating the keys?

Comment: It is not the password of the ssh key. I pasted the code and it will not be formated.

Answer (score 0):

An RSA key with 4096 bit as a key size might not always be supported.

Try and create a default key, with:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -P ""
```

See if that key (with 1024 as a default size, and [an old PEM format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309)) is better supported.