# Trying to clone repo from Google Cloud Source Repositories using SSH authentication

Tags: git, ssh, google-cloud-repository

I am trying to clone an empty repository from the **Google Cloud Resource Repositories**. So far I have:

- Created an empty repository on **Google Cloud Source Repositories**.
- Generated an ssh key (default name "id_rsa") from my local machine (Windows 10).
- Registered the contents of the public key (id_rsa.pub) in the **Register SSH Key** section of **Cloud Source Repositories**.
- Opened **Git Bash** and run `git clone ssh://blah@gmail.com@source.developers.google.com:2022/p/some-project/r/some-repository`

However, it fails with this response:

```
Cloning into 'some-repository'...
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/blah/.ssh/id_rsa':
fatal: could not fetch refs from ssh://blah@gmail.com@source.developers.google.com:2022/p/some-project/r/some-repository
```

I am running **Git Bash** from **Windows 10**

It does label **SSH Authentication** as **BETA** on **Cloud Resource Repositories**, which makes me wonder if it might not be fully functional yet.
Has anyone managed to connect to **Cloud Resource Repositories** via SSH?

Any help or advice much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try first to use an SSH key without passphrase, and make sure to create it [with the legacy format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309):

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -P ""
```

(The `-m PEM` is for producing the legacy format)

That will overwrite your previous key: register the new `id_rsa.pub` content, and try again.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I already tried without a passphrase but it didn't work either.
For now I have resorted to using "Google Cloud SDK"

Comment: @GlenAu-Yeung did you try with the -m PEM: that is the important part, to generate a key to the legacy format.

Comment: Thank you so much- It worked. In the end I created a key with a passphrase but using the -m option as you suggested. However, I couldn't find anything on the -m option in the man page or documentation for ssh-keygen. Would you mind directing me to where I can find more information on this option?

Answer (score 0):

Type `ssh-keygen` and press ENTER. A passphrase is optional.

Note: if the `ssh-keygen` is not recognized you need to install OpenSSH.