# Yarnpkg can't add private package via ssh althought I've been added it

Tags: javascript, git, npm, ssh, yarnpkg

I can't perform `yarn` to install my packages.

Some of my packages are private like this:

```
"my-package": "git+ssh://git@mycompany.com:company/my-package#0.2.35"
```

It produce this error.

```
git@my-company.com: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

But I can git clone them via ssh, how do I solve this problem?

Comment: If your ssh key is password protected, yarn will not interrupt the installation for asking the password. The only solution i am aware of is, remove the password from ssh key and try `yarn install`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your default (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`) private SSH key is passphrase protected (passphrase, not password), then try at least to add it to the ssh agent.

As in [`yarnpkg/yarn` issue 3942](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3942#issuecomment-335976912)

> To anyone else from the future like myself `ssh-add -l -E md5` (for OpenSSH >= 6.8) seems to have cleared the issue up, while proclaiming that no identities were added.

To check which key is actually used, set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to `ssh -v` before your command.

Also, try and register another SSH key, this time [with a legacy format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309) (if your current key has 70 chars per line)