# Repeat `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` to access private repository

Tags: git, github

Upon generating ssh-keys to github account,  I create a new file to hold the the keys as:

```
  ssh-keygen  -f ~/.ssh/github
```

Then do the following steps:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/github
```

Add add the public key to github account.

However,  after restart the machine, it prompt that I have not the access to the private repo,

I have to repeat

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/github
```

to gain the access to the repository.

Everytime, I re-login a terminal, the above steps should be repeated.

How could solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could follow "[Auto-launching ssh-agent on Git for Windows](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.16/user/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows)" (valid also for Linux), by copying into your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc file in Git shell functions which can start the SSH agent for you.

The `.bashrc` is the one which will be always read, as in "[What are the functional differences between `.profile` `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`](https://serverfault.com/a/261807/783)"

> `.bash_profile` or `.profile` is read by login shells, along with `.bashrc`; subshells read only `.bashrc`

Make sure your SSH key is working (`ssh -i /path/to/private/key git@github.com`), because recent version of Git uses the [new OpenSSH format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309).