# Getting wrong id when verifying rsa key

Tags: git, github, ssh

I've created a new ssh key using:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C <my-email>
```

I've added the new key to github in my GitHub account settings. I've added the following to my "config" in my `.ssh` folder:

```
Host *
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeychain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

When I attempted to verify my GitHub account by using:

```
ssh -T -ai ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@github.com
```

I get back someone else as an acknowledgement.

```
Hi xxxx/yyyy! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access
```

What could be causing this?

I've deleted the old id_rsa keys and generated new ones.

I expected it to show:

```
Hi my name/my_repo! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to double-check that your `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is indeed registered in [new GitHub setting account](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).

The [testing SSH](https://help.github.com/en/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection) page mentions:

> Hi *username*! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
>   provide shell access.

So it should not be `name/myrepo`, but only `name`.

The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1623617/user1623617) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57016418/getting-wrong-id-when-verifying-rsa-key/57016919?noredirect=1#comment100575917_57016919) a [passphrase issue](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent):

> Started a new terminal session.
>   Ran eval `ssh-agent -s`, added the new rsa key using: `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I did checked out the link you had previously prior to this post. The key is a new rsa key.  I've deleted the old one in hope that it was the cause of the problem but it still shows the same result.  I am also not sure why the reply from Github returns a path to a repo along with the username.  Any further help is much appreciated.

Comment: @user1623617 Just for context, what OS are you using? What version (of the OS and of Git)?

Comment: @user1623617 For testing, can you make a key (and registered it) with the old openssl PEM format? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309

Comment: Got it figured out.  Started a new terminal session.  Ran ```eval `ssh-agent -s` ```.  Added the new rsa key using: ```ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa```.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @user1623617 Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, with a link for documentation.