# Add GitHub private repo to Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, github, repository

I am trying to add my private GitHub repo to a Jenkins job.

I selected source control 'Git', put the ssh link to my GitHub and selected my credentials but it still gives me this error.

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h -- git@github.com:DanSmith/MyPrivateRepo.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.**.***.*' to the list of known hosts.
Load key "/tmp/ssh87617326.key": invalid format
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow "[**Setup Jenkins for private GitHub repository**](https://medium.com/facademy/setup-jenkins-for-private-repository-9060f54eeac9)" from [**Maciej Najbar**](https://twitter.com/maciejnajbar).

The steps involve:

- creating a dedicated private SSH key

  ```
  ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -P "" -C "jenkins.me" -f jenkinskey
  ```

That will create a jenkinskey/jenkinskey.pub, without passphrase (since Jenkins would not be able to enter one at runtime).
Its format should be (for the private key) an [SSH one, not openssh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309): 64 chars wide, note 76.

- registering that [public (not private) key in your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)
- registering your *private* key as a Credential in Jenkins (assuming your have the [SSH Credentials plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-credentials) installed)
  Make sure to copy `----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` up to `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`, without missing a '-' (as [mentioned here](https://serverfault.com/questions/854208/ssh-suddenly-returning-invalid-format/854212#comment1224047_854212))

[image: https://miro.medium.com/max/2065/1*6m49tJmEuRQfarRFXoZczA.png]

- make sure Jenkins knowns about github.com

  ```
  ssh -T git@github.com
  ```

Even if the ~jenkins/.ssh has no key, that will add github.com to your ~jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts.

- Finally, use the credential name your entered before for your Git configuration of your Jenkins job:

[image: https://miro.medium.com/max/2577/1*Lo9Jc4YAlHJfaHF6uktaHA.png]

Comment: I've done all that but get the error I said above in the last step after adding the repo url and setting the credentials

Comment: @Dan does a `ssh -Tv -i /path/to/private/key git@github.com` works?

Comment: Yes it says successfully authenticated

Comment: @Dan Then, if the private key is entered in the Jenkins SSH Credentials, and its entry is used in the job settings (and there is no passphrase associated with said key), this should work.

Comment: There is a passphrase but I entered it.

Comment: In GitHub I put the public key in Settings>SSH Keys and in Jenkins in the credentials I put the private key and passphrase

Comment: @Dan The all point of the answer is to highlight that a private key used by Jenkins should be created **without** any passphrase.

Comment: @Dan From the article: Jenkins is a service and it won't be able to enter passphrase when connecting to ssh

Comment: @Dan the ssh-keygen I mention  in my answer is made to create a private key *without* passphrase. For a reason. It will work.

Comment: Can't it easily be hacked then since I have to open a port also to connect while Im not home?

Comment: @Dan No, it cannot be "easily hacked": that is why you create a dedicated SSH key *just for Jenkins*, to be registered in your GitHub account, separate from your usual SSH key (which can have a passphrase): if you had the slightest doubt, you can revoke that one key and regenerate another.

Comment: @Dan But again, try and follow my answer: it should work.

Comment: How do I get rid of / revote the current key I got from ssh-genkey before doing the new one?

Comment: @Dan Simply remove it from your SSH keys in your GitHub settings, and remove it from your Jenkins SSH Credentials

Comment: I forgot the command to get the private key from ssh that I did earlier, do you happen to know it?

Comment: @Dan I have included in the answer the ssh-keygen to generate a new one, but I don't know about your previous one.

Comment: It's asking for a password `[sudo] password for jenkins:`

Comment: @Dan In which environment (user session) are you typing this? You can litteraly type that on any computer: the private key is copied in Jenkins and the public one on GitHub.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199453/discussion-between-dan-and-vonc).

Comment: @VonC, no doubt this will be a popular answer. When discussion concluded, please update your answer so as to capture any missing details, same for the OP's questiion and hopefully it can be marked as "answered". Thx from all of us for your usual  S/O excellence!

Comment: @IanW no problem. The discussion is still ongoing!