# Permission denied with mutiple github accounts

Tags: git, ssh

I'm trying to set up personal git account along with my work account. I followed this guide https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/manage-multiple-github-accounts-the-ssh-way-2dadc30ccaca/
and my ~/.ssh/config is (some-name is my user name for personal github account)

```
host github.com
   Hostname github.com
   User git
   AddKeysToAgent yes
   UseKeychain yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
host some-name.github.com
   Hostname github.com
   Identityfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
```

After this, I ran `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal` which was successful.

However, when I do `ssh -T some-name.github.com`, it fails with 
`somename@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)`
The work account is working fine. I also uploaded newly generated public key on github account.

My git config --list shows user.name=some-name.

**update**: based on VonC's response, I was able to get `ssh -T some-name.github.com` to run successfully. However, I am still getting following error when I try to push code into a repo in github account.

```
ERROR: Permission to some-name/docker-react.git denied to User.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I checked the ssh keys uploaded on github, and it is correct.

Comment: alternative: `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`, 
`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal`, 
`ssh -T git@github.com`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, add User git to your second config:

```
host some-name.github.com
   Hostname github.com
   Identityfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
   User git
```

The [OP agyeya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3934499/agyeya) had to then modify the remote `origin` URL accordingly:

```
git remote set-url origin git@some-name.github.com:some-name/docker-react.git
```

---

If this is still not working (assuming the public key was registered to your GitHub account):

Try and create first keys without associated passphrase, to test it out.
That will avoid the ssh-agent need (again, for testing)

See "[what is the correct format for private key in Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309)", to create one with the old PEM format:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -P "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
```

Comment: @agyeya You had selected the right answer before. What happened?

Comment: @agyeya Is "some-name" your own GitHub account? Or are you declared as a collaborator in the repo `some-name/docker-react`

Comment: "some-name" is my own github account. One thing I noticed- it's using somename@github.com. Is this userid generated internally by github using my name?

Comment: I essentially have 2 id_rsa(_personal) files. Could it be that wrong one is being picked? Although I have explicitly done ```ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal``` , not sure if this getting picked during git push.

Comment: Was able to solve git push with this: ```git remote set-url origin git@some-name.github.com:some-name/docker-react.git ``` What happened was the remote url alrerady had some-name in it, and so I missed it while setting remote earlier. I ended up using ```git remote set-url origin git@github.com:some-name/docker-react.git```

Comment: @agyeya Well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thanks for the help VonC. However, I guess I framed the sentence incorrectly- What works is ```git remote set-url origin git@some-name.github.com:some-name/docker-react.git``` Please update this in your answer so that no one finds incorrect info

Answer (score 0):

Did you upload your public key to github? In github you can check which public keys are uploaded, see if you uploaded it and that you uploaded the correct one.

Comment: Yes, I uploaded the key

Answer (score 0):

**You can define key at a repository level.**

**Configuration core.sshCommand:**
From Git version 2.10.0, you can configure this per repo or globally, so you don't have to set the environment variable any more!

```
git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example -F /dev/null"
git pull
git push
```

> This will add a key entry in the .git/config file. So whenever you
>   perform any git actions this will use the defined ssh key.

**Environment variable GIT_SSH_COMMAND:**
From Git version 2.3.0, you can use the environment variable GIT_SSH_COMMAND like this:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example" git clone example
```

Note that -i can sometimes be overridden by your config file, in which case, you should give SSH an empty config file, like this:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example -F /dev/null" git clone example
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to command in your computer, type "Manage Windows Credential "
   [step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU0Ya.png)

2. Remove your history github records.
   [step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUOws.png)

3. commit your code git bash again and then it works