# 'ssh -vT git@github.com' results in error "kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host"

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

[The way I configuration the SSH key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViVNM.png), I generate a new SSH key, and add it to my GitHub account, but something is wrong. I tried many ways, but I could not fix it.

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
```

Output:

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [111.40.234.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/dell/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /c/Users/dell/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/dell/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/dell/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/dell/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/dell/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/dell/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/dell/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/dell/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/dell/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

What can I do?

Comment: You seem to be using Windows and Cygwin. These details should probably be mentioned in your question. Also, how is your `ssh` client configured, and how specifically are you tel\ing it which key to use for Github?

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are using a VPN connection in your network and the VPN may have disabled port 22, so you need to cancel the VPN use or change the GitHub connection to port 443.

Edit `~/.ssh/config` file, and save it.

```bash
Host github.com
    HostName ssh.github.com
    User git
    Port 443
```

Again test (as [root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser)):

```bash
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Output:

```
The authenticity of host '[ssh.github.com]:443 ([20.205.243.160]:443)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[ssh.github.com]:443' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Hi xxxxxx You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there're too many keys in your `~/.ssh/`. Point `ssh` to the exact key you use. In `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github.com
    User git
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa # or whatever key you use with Github
```

Then try `ssh -Tv git@github.com` again.

Comment: I have only one key,and I try this way,but it still can not.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one key, try and regenerate it with [the old PEM format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309), and no passphrase, for testing:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -m PEM
```

Copy the content of `id_rsa.pub` to your GitHub profile, and try again.