# git issue - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, bitbucket

I haven't changed the SSH key for the bitbucket for a while. All of sudden, it stopped working and I am seeing the following error from my source tree and command line.

```
Pushing to ssh://git@bitbucket.example.com:7998/project1/com.example.frontend.git
git@bitbucket.example.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Pushing to ssh://git@bitbucket.example.com:7998/project1/com.example.frontend.git
git@bitbucket.example.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I had to change the host/url for this post.

So I went inside the directory where this project is and ran this command, but got the same error.

```
git push
git@bitbucket.example.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

When I ran 'git config --list', I see the full list of config with my user name/company email/remote origin url.

I checked my public SSH key(which is in my account in BitBucket) with my local ssh key under ~/.ssh. It is identical.

Is there anything else that I can check or try?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test if your public key is registered to your hosted bitbucket account.

```
ssh -Tv -p 7998 -i ~/.ssh/mykey git@bitbucket.example.com
```

If it does work (meaning you get a "Shell access is disabled."), chekc your ~/.ssh/config content.

[The OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/826323/user826323) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59743754/git-issue-permission-denied-publickey/59745487?noredirect=1#comment105661692_59745487):

> I regenerated the ssh key, and it started working...
>   I don't know why the old ssh key didn't work.

Sometimes, depending on OpenSSH version, it can be a format issue:
See "[what is the correct format for private key in Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309)".

Comment: i am not getting "Shell access is disabled".

Comment: @user826323 What are you getting? And do you have a ~/.ssh/config file? Also what is your OS (and OS version) as well as your Git version?

Comment: i regenerated the ssh key and it started working.. i don't know why the old ssh key didn't work..

Comment: @user826323 Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.