# Spring Cloud / Jgit / Github failing with SSH

Tags: github, ssh, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, jgit

- Windows 10 Pro x64
- JDK 11.0.6
- spring-cloud-config-server 2.2.2.RELEASE

I'm setting up Spring Cloud Config server. Works fine with a file system backend. Works fine with a **https / basic auth** github backend. Now I'm trying to set it up for SSH so I don't have to put my username and password in the config file.

It's my understanding that Spring Cloud Config / jgit will use all the default SSH settings, correct? I have done the following:

1. `ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096 -C "xxx@xxx.net"` -- took all the default files and NO passphrase. files got created in C:\Users\xxx.ssh.
2. opened c:\users\xxx.ssh\id_rsa.pub, selected all, c&p to github
3. ran `git clone git@github.com:xxx/Config.git`, copied SHA256 fingerprint into yes/no/fingerprint prompt, clone was successful
4. edited known_hosts and removed IP, so now it just reads `github.com ssh-rsa AAAA...`
5. application.properties:

   spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=git@github.com:xxx/Config.git

   spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true

   spring.cloud.config.server.git.strict-host-key-checking=false

   spring.cloud.config.server.git.skip-ssl-validation=true

This results in:

```
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519) ~[jsch-0.1.54.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:146) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Why am I getting an Auth fail?

Comment: I have seen https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1603... which redirects here!

Comment: If anyone still looking at this issue and you're sure it is related to SSH key format (like [this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1251#issuecomment-901097861)) then one possible solution would be to use *spring-cloud-config-server* version 3.1.0 or newer. They updated the problematic JGit version 5.1.3 to 5.12.0 in this [commit](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/commit/8d8451b694f22cebb64781b412fa78c45da0db97#diff-033c69ea9fcdbc0b950d10a7017bd2bf4101837217fe074f111b45467718883a) so that Config Server can properly use OpenSSH-formatted keys as well.

Answer (score 3):

One possible reason would be the server running as Admin instead of your regular User account, which means it would not find `%USERPROFILE%\id_rsa`.

The [OP SledgeHammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5004822/sledgehammer) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61484258/spring-cloud-jgit-github-failing-with-ssh/61580572#comment108930434_61580572):

> Jgit works against `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` on Windows.
>   My company remaps those to a `P:` drive (although it doesn't remap `USERPROFILE`).
>   And the openssh tools (and git itself) works against `USERPROFILE`.

That means Jsch will need `.ssh` in `P:\`

---

Another reason would be the [format of the private key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309) (try with a private key generated using the old OpenSSH format, for testing)

Finally, [double-check the URI used](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1451#issuecomment-523246551)

> After investigating the jgit API, I've worked out the problem.
>   The URI in the Spring Cloud Config documentation is incorrect. The documentation lists the format to be
>
> ```
> git@host:port/repo1.git
> ```
>
> It should instead be
>
> ```
> ssh://git@host:port/repo1.git
> ```
>
> So in my case, it worked once I changed it to ssh://git@mygit:2222/secops/secrets.git

(you don't need the port 2222, just to use '`/`' instead of '`:`')

Comment: @SledgeHammer Good catch. I have updated the answer and included your comment for more visibility. I'll leave the answer there, as it could help others with the same issue.