# Using SSH keyfile with Netbeans for remote development

Tags: ssh, netbeans-8, ssh-keys, netbeans-platform

I want to do remote development on a raspberry pi using Netbeans IDE. Everything works fine when using password based authentication.
When I try to use SSH key based authentication, the Netbeans 12 IDE reports

```
Contents of file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa is not a valid ssh private key.
```

My host system is MacOS and I generated the SSH key pair using the command `ssh-keygen` without any additional parameters and setting no pass phrase.

Contents of the file is :

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
LOTS OF RANDOM TEXT HERE
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I'm also able to ssh into the remote machine using a terminal just fine without a password.

Answer (score 4):

Try and regenerate your key (and register the public key again to the remote server authorized_keys) using the [old PEM format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309):

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -P "" -t rsa
```

See if Netbeans does recognize this format then.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, it worked for me.

Comment: ssh-keygen -m PEM dose the trick for me ! ty