# Git push with SSH remote error: Load key "/path/to/file_id_rsa": invalid format

Tags: git, github, ssh, github-actions

I'm trying to use `git push` with SSH remote from GitHub CI action and get an error: `Load key "/tmp/341b5794-f0a2-4534-90dd-f791510ec77a_id_rsa": invalid format`

Key is in repository secret. I get its info with `ssh-keygen -l -v -f key_id_rsa` and its output equals to output on my local machine. From my machine I can push with this key

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new -i /tmp/341b5794-f0a2-4534-90dd-f791510ec77a_id_rsa'
```

Thewe was the `/tmp/341b5794-f0a2-4534-90dd-f791510ec77a_id_rsa.pub` file

Full `ssh -v` inside of `git push` output:

```
+ git push dest-push-remote gh-pages
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.112.4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: SELinux support disabled
debug1: identity file /tmp/341b5794-f0a2-4534-90dd-f791510ec77a_id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /tmp/341b5794-f0a2-4534-90dd-f791510ec77a_id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-10d0a39d
debug1: no match: babeld-10d0a39d
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:1
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.112.4' to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /tmp/341b5794-f0a2-4534-90dd-f791510ec77a_id_rsa RSA SHA256:1xl0uMTaSpIRCnMFIGCf9zC4/CTHXPCroAk1cJIK6qY explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /tmp/341b5794-f0a2-4534-90dd-f791510ec77a_id_rsa RSA SHA256:1xl0uMTaSpIRCnMFIGCf9zC4/CTHXPCroAk1cJIK6qY explicit
debug1: Server accepts key: /tmp/341b5794-f0a2-4534-90dd-f791510ec77a_id_rsa RSA SHA256:1xl0uMTaSpIRCnMFIGCf9zC4/CTHXPCroAk1cJIK6qY explicit
Load key "/tmp/341b5794-f0a2-4534-90dd-f791510ec77a_id_rsa": invalid format
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

**UPD.** After discussion in comments I tried to generate new key pair on a Linux machine and it works. Problem in different formats of keys generated on the Linux machine and on a MacOS machine:

The MacOS generated key begins with `BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY`. The Linux generated key begins with `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY`. I'm investigating wat's the difference but it will be helpful if any specialist suggest me some information

Comment: I believe you're missing the important line here `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).`. Make sure the public key of that is in the repository's [deploy keys](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys) with write access to it can write to the repository.

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne You've missed the important line here: `Load key "/tmp/341b5794-f0a2-4534-90dd-f791510ec77a_id_rsa": invalid format`

Comment: What is the header line for the private key (e.g., `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`)?  Is it listed as being encrypted?

Comment: I checked this very key from the local machine and it works, so public key in deploy keys of repository should match it.

And I printed first and last N symbols and it starts with `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----` and ends with `-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----` so it doesn't looks like corrupted content

Comment: In my previous comment I meant `BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY`. After that I thought about this header. Why `OPENSSH` but not `RSA`? Then I generated new key pair on Linux machine and tryed this. And it works. Now I'm investigating why on MacOS machine `ssh-keygen` generates other key format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the private key format differs, that means, as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309) that:

- one platform is using openssh prior to 7.8, with an old PEM 64-chars per line format.
- one is using a more recent OpenSSH format, 70-chars per line.

You can force a recent openSSH to generate the old format with:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -P "" -f afile
```