# Jenkins Failed to connect to Gitlab Repository

Tags: jenkins, ssh, gitlab, devops

I have generated a pubic SSH key on my Ubuntu 20.04 server with the user Jenkins, and my key is stored  below :

> /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

I have set that public Key  on my Gitlab SSH parameters, And I had also create a Credentials in Jenkins for SSH Private key, where i pasted the private key i had generate for my Jenkin's user in linux 20.04 remote server.
When i try to clone the projet using SSH, i get the error :

> Failed to connect to repository : Error performing git command: /usr/lib/git-core ls-remote -h git@gitlab.com:project/repository.git HEAD*

Need a helping hand to solve this problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzHHq.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, check that your key is indeed considered when doing ssh with the `jenkins` account:

```
ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com
```

You will see where SSH is looking for your keys, and if `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa` is used.
You should see a [welcome message](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#verify-that-you-can-connect).

Second, Check the Jenkins logs to see if there is any additional clues.

You might need to use an SSH key using the [old PEM format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309):

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -P "" -f afile
```

Comment: I Try to  this command ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com
 and  I saw the welcome message, But no Log on Jenkins was recorded

Comment: @BoubacarFofana in command-line, can you check if `git ls-remote git@gitlab.com:project/repository.git` works? (replacing project and repository by the right names)

Comment: yes it worked here is the result `41cf42a0784a refs/heads/dev
8a5e73286edb2feba89f15d2b656b55d9e49bdac refs/heads/main
db1665aca17037954d2ff659093c24c0e1e1170a refs/heads/master
77abc7c7c1d9fa2cc4eb92b7c314cd00dcae326a refs/merge-requests/10/head
55d54746fdfeb1c777044809e43892287d80002e refs/merge-requests/10/merge
58624e027802daf0326aded7779f1b14bd3345e7 refs/merge-requests/11/head
83c373fb42d246949f7f467bab34d3accc736bc2 refs/merge-requests/11/merge
e198cc411df8c68230e6509c5311114fd94af835 refs/merge-requests/9/head `

Comment: @BoubacarFofana Can you try again, this time with an SSH key using the old PEM format, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309? Check that new key also work in command line, then use this new private key in your Jenkins credentials and see if the job definition works.

Comment: Hi I tried again but it didnt work. I decided  use the jenkins container and i had the same issue. 
When I try to use public repository from GitLab ou Github, everything goes fine. When it's about a private repository it failed.

Comment: @BoubacarFofana And that same access to private repo works from command line?

Comment: From command line yes. It Worked and i have a welcome message to my Git account

Comment: @BoubacarFofana Strange: if the private key (especially in the old format) is recorded in the Jenkins credentials, it should work.

Comment: as i use Docker now I have the same issue. Im still using the old format of the private key  and i have  `Failed to connect to repository : Error performing git command:  ls-remote -h git@gitlab.com:project xxx HEAD`

Comment: @BoubacarFofana Can you `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv` first, then try again? That should show you where git is looking for its keys.

Comment: can you please explain Step By Step how should i do the following command `$GIT_SSH_COMMAND` because nothing happened in my terminal want type `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv' `

Comment: @BoubacarFofana I meant stop Jenkins, type the `export` command, as the `jenkins` account, and restart Jenkins. That way, you will see more details in Jenkins logs.